# iOS - Swift - UIProgressView Animation Update

Tags: ios, animation, swift, nstimer, uiprogressview

I was wondering if it is possible to know when the animation ends in a UIProgressView

Because during the animation, the progress value is already set to 1, even if it's half-way on your screen (during test)

I've noticed that using a bigger value than 1 in 
`TimerBar.setProgress( 0< Float < 1, animated : true)` slow the animation. Bigger is the Float (bigger than one) , slower is the animation.

I would like to trigger an event when the animation ends and when the bar is full.

Thanks for your help !

PS : I know that using a NSTime can be an alternative, but I would like to try this way !

EDIT : I have noticed that the value (normally between 0 and 1) is also the time when you animate the bar 
TimerBar.setProgress(10, animated :  true) 
The bar will take ten seconds to fill !
 I've finally couples it with NSTimer.

But the other problem is the bar update now. 
The bar won't care if you simply choose NO in the animation parameter while it's already performing another animation

For example :
TimerBar.setProgress(0.5, animated : false)
TimerBar.setProgress(1, animated : true)

Here the first line will be simply ignored. Any solution/ ?